# UIView perpetual linear animation with collision detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, collision-detection

I'm trying to make a circular UIView animate in a particular direction until it collides with the borders of the view (which is full screen, so basically the borders of the device), at which point it will reflect off it and continue on its way infinitely. However, I'm not really sure how to pose my question, so I'm having trouble finding any information on it. I already have the view, the direction it will move in, and its velocity. I'm just not sure how to handle an animation like that.

Any advice is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CADisplayLink` to continuously update the position of the view, synced with the refresh rate of the screen. The update method that that display link triggers will take into account the current x and y velocity of the view and update the frame based on it. If at ever point the x- or y-coordinate goes under or over a limit (0 or screen width/height), reverse the appropriate velocity value and recalculate the position.